# Basic Question: K-theory of a sphere bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology, riemann-surfaces

Does anyone know how to compute the topological K-theory of the unit tangent bundle for a compact connected Riemann surface of genus greater than one?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Complex K-theory?  A 3-manifold has K^0 = H^0 + H^2 and K^1 = H^1 + H^3.  Looks like Z^{2g+1} + Z/(2g -2) in degree zero and Z^{2g+1} in degree 1.

Comment: @DavidTreumann Thank you very much for your comment. Do you have any reference to understand the isomorphism? Do you know what it looks like if we replace the space the unit tangent bundle on the Riemann surface by a more general quotient of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$ with $\Gamma$ a Fuchsian group acting not necessarily freely on the hyperbolic upper half-plane?